# Quadratic equations question

Tags: quadratics

let $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ be 2 quadratic eqs. with one non-rational root common and integral coefficients.
prove $P(x) = r.Q(x)$, for some rational no. $r$

TRIED ANSWER:

Let $P(x)= ax^2 + bx + c$

$\Rightarrow$ $x = \frac{-b \pm \surd b^2-4ac}{2a}$

Let $Q(x)= mx^2 + nx + o$

$\Rightarrow$ $x' = \frac{-n \pm \surd n^2-4mo}{2m}$

If one root of $P(x)$ =  one root of $Q(x)$

then assume $\Rightarrow$ $\frac{-b + \surd b^2-4ac}{2a}$ = $\frac{-n + \surd n^2-4mo}{2m}$

As they both are irrational, comparing the two we get the irrational part equal.

Hence both the roots are same for the two equations

**OR**

They are the same equations with different leading coefficients.

THUS

$P(x)=k*Q(x)$

*for some constant k.*

Comment: Do you mean polynomials? What have you tried?

Comment: @AlokRanjan: You didn't answer Daniel R.

Comment: @AlokRanjan You will receive better quality answers if you include your own working up to the point you got stuck.  Then posters have a better idea of where you're going wrong and can point you in the right direction.

Comment: For the statement to be true, I think that it need to be assumed that $P$ and $Q$ have rational coefficients.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Why is the question on hold??

Comment: @AlokRanjan: The reason your question was put on hold is written below. Since you edited the question, it has been put in the reopen queue, but it takes time for it to be reopened (if it should be) because it takes five votes from people with at least $3,000$ votes.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false. For example, $P(x)=(x-\sqrt 2) = x^2 - 2\sqrt 2 x + 2$ and $Q(x) = x^2-2$ have one non-rational root in common. However, there is no rational number $r$ such that $P(x) = r\cdot Q(x)$.

Comment: @shauryagupta, that was added just 5 minutes ago...and the OP never answered the first question posed to him.

Comment: @AlokRanjan Your statement does not say that they should be.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $Q(x) = dx^2+ex+f$. Let the roots of $P(x)$ be $\alpha,\beta$ and of $Q(x) $ be $\alpha,\gamma$. $\alpha$ is the common irrational root.
$\alpha+\beta=\frac{-b}a$. Since $-\frac ba$ is irrational, $\alpha+\beta$ must also be irrational. $\implies\beta=-\alpha$. $\implies -\frac ba=0 \implies b = 0$
Similarly, $\gamma = -\alpha$  and $e=0$.

$\alpha\cdot\beta=\frac ca \implies-\alpha^2=\frac ca = \frac fd$.

$P(x)=ax^2+c$ and $Q(x)=dx^2+f$.
$P(x)=ax^2-a\cdot\alpha^2$ and $Q(x)=dx^2-d\alpha^2$.
$P(x)=ax^2-a\cdot\alpha^2=\frac ad(dx^2-d\cdot\alpha^2)=\frac adQ(x)=r\cdot Q(x)$.